# How to make Emacs read buffer from stdin on start?

Tags: unix, vim, emacs

With Vim I can easily do

```
$ echo 123 | vim -
```

Is it possible to do with Emacs?

```
$ echo 123 | emacs23
... Emacs starts with a Welcome message

$ echo 123 | emacs23 -
... Emacs starts with an empty *scratch* buffer and “Unknown option”

$ echo 123 | emacs23 --insert -
... “No such file or directory”, empty *scratch* buffer
```

Is it really impossible to read a buffer from a unix pipe?

**Edit**: As a solution, I wrote a shell wrapper named `emacspipe`:

```
#!/bin/sh
TMP=$(mktemp) && cat > $TMP && emacs23 $TMP ; rm $TMP
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Correct, it is impossible to read a buffer from stdin.

The only mention of stdin in the Emacs info pages is [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html), which says:

> In batch mode, Emacs does not display
>   the text being edited, and the
>   standard terminal interrupt characters
>   such as `C-z` and `C-c` continue to
>   have their normal effect.  The
>   functions `prin1`, `princ` and `print`
>   output to `stdout` instead of the echo
>   area, while `message` and error
>   messages output to `stderr`. 
>   Functions that would normally read
>   from the minibuffer take their input
>   from `stdin` instead.

And the [`read`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Functions.html#Input-Functions) function can read from `stdin`, but only in batch mode.

So, you can't even work around this by writing custom elisp.

Comment: I mean no disrespect to anyone, but this is abhorrent.  This is a very basic editor feature and GNU EMACS has been around for decades.  It should be built in.

Answer (score 42):

You could use [process substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution):

```
$ emacs --insert <(echo 123)
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer that gets closest to the Vim functionality. Pretty much just moving the piped part into a subprocess substitution.

Comment: @dbmikus I can't decide which I prefer between mine and Tomasz Obrębski's..

Comment: Tomasz's results in me getting the following error for some reason:

`emacs: standard input is not a tty`

Comment: Oh indeed! I assumed he'd tested before posting.

Comment: Hmm.. I just tried Tomasz Obrębski's again, and it works for me this time :/

Comment: Maybe it depends on the month.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I have a “wrap” function written with Emacs:

cat file-with-long-lines | emacs -nw --batch -Q --insert <(cat) --eval '(progn (fill-paragraph)(message (buffer-string)))' 2>&1

Comment: what about `(t)csh` shell which is the default in the `bsd` family who lack such a feature?

Comment: Too bad it does no work with emacsclient

Comment: This is a very cool trick! I used it to make an executable Bash script that's also an Emacs lisp file that is effectively a single-file Emacs app installer and runner. https://github.com/jgkamat/matrix-client-el/blob/master/misc/matrix-client-standalone.el

Answer (score 14):

You can redirect to a file, then open the file.  e.g.

```
echo 123 > temp; emacs temp
```

jweede notes that if you want the temp file to automatically be removed, you can:

```
echo 123 > temp; emacs temp; rm temp
```

The Emacsy way to do this is *to run the shell command in Emacs*.

```
M-! echo 123 RET
```

That gives you a buffer named *Shell Command Output* with the results of the command.

Comment: Yes, I know there is emacsy way, but I hoped it may be used unixy way. Creating a temporary file is not a very nice option (I have to remember to delete it later).

Comment: tacking on ';rm temp' should delete the file once emacs closes

Comment: such as: `echo 123 > temp; emacs temp; rm temp`

Comment: In general, there is a high impedance between Emacs and Unix.  Or at least between Emacs and the traditional Unix work flow.

Comment: @jweede   If you want to add M-! part of my answer to yours, then I could delete my answer.  There is a large overlap in our answers, but I think meta-bang is important to future readers.

Comment: temp may already exist in the current directory, it's not safe; as a solution, I wrote a wrapper: `TMP=$(mktemp) && cat > $TMP && emacs23 $TMP ; rm $TMP`. Thanks everybody!

Comment: An even more emacs way to do this is to C-u M-! (prefix argument + shell command), which inserts the output at the current point. (the shell to command to execute would be for example `cat the/file/you/want`)

Answer (score 10):

It is possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879746/idomatic-batch-processing-of-text-in-emacs

Here is echo in an emacs script (copied from the above link):

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script
(condition-case nil
    (let (line)
      (while (setq line (read-from-minibuffer ""))
        (princ line)
        (princ "\n")))
  (error nil))
```

or to read it into a buffer and then print it out all in one go

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script
(with-temp-buffer
  (progn
    (condition-case nil
    (let (line)
      (while (setq line (read-from-minibuffer ""))
        (insert line)
        (insert "\n")))
      (error nil))
    (princ (buffer-string))
    ))
```

Comment: Why not do `(let (line) (while (setq line (ignore-errors (read-from-minibuffer ""))) (insert line) (insert "\n")))` instead of using `condition-case`?

Answer (score 7):

This works:

```
echo 123 | emacs --insert <(cat)
```

but, for some reason, only with graphical-mode emacs (Gnome,Konsole,GNU Emacs 23.4.1). The command:

```
echo 123 | emacs -nw --insert <(cat)
```

generates an error 'emacs: standard input is not a tty'. The same error appears when tried in raw text console.

Comment: `echo 123 | exec emacs -nw --insert <(cat) </dev/tty` should work.

Comment: That works; why the exec? This also works: 
emacs -nw --insert <(echo 123) </dev/tty

Comment: Go figure: works beautifully on Emacs (w32) on Cygwin, where lots of other settings of mine do not

Comment: You using `emacs 0<$TTY 1>$TTY -nw` make emacs escape from pipeline.

Answer (score 7):

It's [possible to create a simple shell function](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/emacs-read-stdin) which works as it is reading from stdin (although in fact it is writing to a temporary file then reading that). Here's the code I'm using:

```bsh
# The emacs or emacsclient command to use
function _emacsfun
{
    # Replace with `emacs` to not run as server/client
    emacsclient -c -n $@
}

# An emacs 'alias' with the ability to read from stdin
function e
{
    # If the argument is - then write stdin to a tempfile and open the
    # tempfile.
    if [[ $# -ge 1 ]] && [[ "$1" == - ]]; then
        tempfile="$(mktemp emacs-stdin-$USER.XXXXXXX --tmpdir)"
        cat - > "$tempfile"
        _emacsfun --eval "(find-file \"$tempfile\")" \
            --eval '(set-visited-file-name nil)' \
            --eval '(rename-buffer "*stdin*" t))'
    else
        _emacsfun "$@"
    fi
}
```

You just use the function as an alias for emacs, e.g.

```
echo "hello world" | e -
```

or as normal from files

```
e hello_world.txt
```

Replacing `emacs` by `emacsclient` in the function works as well.

Comment: This works well for me, but _emacsfun should be `emacsclient -c -t $@`, or at the very least drop the -n option.  man pages with `emacsclient -t --eval "(man \"$1\")" --eval "(delete-window)"`  (and now you can `helm-swoop` your way to Man Glory!)

Comment: This is the only answer that I could get to work with emacsclient.  I made a shell script out of the basic idea so I can call it from i3 config. +1

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility not mentioned in any of the previous answers is to use `/dev/stdin` if your chosen Unix variant has it.

Simply trying to open `/dev/stdin` directly doesn't work, because Emacs does a few checks and then reports `Symbolic link that points to nonexistent file`. (And if Emacs would have allowed you to load the file, then trying to save it again as `/dev/stdin` would rarely do what the user expected.)

However combining `/dev/stdin` with the `--insert` argument does work:

```
echo 123 | emacs --insert /dev/stdin
```

It should be noted that this version only works when using X. If you need a solution which works in a terminal I suggest you look at [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/821624/326546).

Comment: i got `emacs: standard input is not a tty` message testing it on linux and bsd

Comment: @Chinggis6 Looks like my suggestion only works when using X11. If I first type `unset DISPLAY`, I get the same error message as you.

Comment: @Chinggis6 I updated my answer to point out that it needs X to work and pointed to an answer which works without X.

Answer (score 2):

offhand, something like:

```
$ echo 123 > tmp.txt; emacs tmp.txt
```

or

```
$ echo 123 > tmp.txt; emacs tmp.txt; rm tmp.txt
```

is an option. Emacs just doesn't integrate with UNIX the way vim does.

Comment: It is surprising that Emacs doesn't integrate with UNIX better, given its history and that one of the key tenets of UNIX is that "everything is a file". It feels intuitive to pipe output directly into Emacs.

Comment: @SabreWolfy While GNU Emacs is most commonly hosted on Unix, it isn't "a Unix program" the way Vim is, but rather a Lisp machine that implements a largely platform-independent text editor. (See Richard Hoskins' answer; the "Emacs way" of doing this isn't to pipe shell command into Emacs, but to have invoke the shell command from within Emacs via `M-!`, which automatically captures the resulting output into a temporary buffer.) Holy wars aside, neither editor is "better" than the other; they just have very different perspectives on pretty much everything.

Comment: except when you're in a shell and want to do something like `curl foo.bar | vim -` .. I'm sorry. I meant `curl foo.bar | emacs` except you can't do that

Answer (score 0):

The solution which works for me in bash is shown on [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsPipe):

Add the following function into your *.bashrc*

```
e() {
local TMP;
if [[ "$1" == "-" ]]; then
    TMP="$(mktemp /tmp/emacsstdinXXX)";
    cat >"$TMP";
    if ! emacsclient --alternate-editor /usr/bin/false --eval "(let ((b (create-file-buffer \"*stdin*\"))) (switch-to-buffer b) (insert-file-contents \"${TMP}\") (delete-file \"${TMP}\"))"  > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        emacs --eval "(let ((b (create-file-buffer \"*stdin*\"))) (switch-to-buffer b) (insert-file-contents \"${TMP}\") (delete-file \"${TMP}\"))" &
    fi;
else
    emacsclient --alternate-editor "emacs" --no-wait "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
fi;
}
```