# emacs as a pager?

Tags: shell, emacs, pipe, pager

I am looking for a way to use emacs as my pager command in the shell (for example with man or to scroll the output of an asynchronous command with a large amount of output). I use emacsclient as my $EDITOR, but emacsclient cannot use stdin as its input file. Is there an emacs extension that does this, or failing that, a pager that uses most of the emacs buffer motion and search commands?

I know that I could just be using M-x term or M-x ansi-term and set my $PAGER variable to 'cat', but I am hoping there is something that will integrate with my current habit of using emacs and xterm separately.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution for you, but I fear there is no way to read STDIN.  Seems like quite a limitation....

Comment: this is technically a dupe of the following question - http://superuser.com/questions/31404/how-to-make-emacs-read-buffer-from-stdin-on-start

Answer (score 2):

You can use this shell script as your pager:

```
#!/bin/sh
t=$(tempfile -s .emacs-pager) || exit 1
cat - >> $t
echo 'reading into emacs...'
emacsclient "$t"
rm -f -- $t
```

Save it as something like ~/bin/emacs_pager.sh, make it executable (eg: `chmod +x ~/bin/emacs_pager.sh`), and then set it as the value for the PAGER environment variable (eg: `export PAGER=~/bin/emacs_pager.sh`).

Note: the above shell script came from this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2rr1ha/use_a_buffer_as_pager_from_shellmode/cnik8wb/

Comment: Currently it seems that at least in Linux `tempfile` is deprecated. Even though the script still works, it gives a warning.  Replacing the first line in the script (the second in the file) with:

`t=$(mktemp .emacs-pager.XXXXXXX) || exit 1`

would have the same effect and use the newer and not-deprecated `mktemp`.

Comment: This doesn't work for an infinite stream of data, which `less` easily supports by opening at the top of the file. Is there a way to emulate this behavior in Emacs?

Answer (score 1):

less supports most of the emacs buffer motion key bindings but not the search bindings out of the box.  You may be able to use [lesskey](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lesskey) to customize the key binding to match emacs.