# Use emacs to edit in-memory text

Tags: bash, emacs

Is it possible to somehow edit in-memory text in emacs? (I.e. without going via the file system.)

I'm writing a script in which I need to edit the output of a command and then process the edited text in another command.

I'm thinking of something like

```
command1 | emacs --edit-std-in-and-write-to-stdout | command2
```

Or, alternatively something like

```
TEXT=$(command1)
emacs --edit-this $TEXT | command2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Emacs read buffer from stdin on start?](http://superuser.com/questions/31404/how-to-make-emacs-read-buffer-from-stdin-on-start)

Answer (score 1):

Emacs won't read standard input unless it's running in batch mode. Instead, you can use a command-line option to pass a Lisp form which Emacs will evaluate immediately after initialization:

```
emacs --eval '(shell-command "command1")'
```

This will execute `command1` and capture its output into a buffer named `*Shell Command Output*`, which you can then rename, edit, &c. to taste.

Once done, you can pass the result to `command2` by means of `C-x h M-| command2 RET`; `C-x h` calls mark-whole-buffer so that the region encompasses the entirety of your edited text, and `M-|` calls `shell-command-on-region` to execute `command2` and supply contents of the region on standard input. (If you've rebound either of those chords, just call the relevant function directly via `M-x function-name RET` instead; as with all interactive Emacs Lisp functions, they will use the minibuffer to prompt for the arguments they need.)

As with `shell-command`, `shell-command-on-region` will capture standard output to the `*Shell Command Output*` buffer, replacing whatever happens to be there; if you want to keep around the edited output of `command1`, rename the buffer before invoking `command2`.)

One further note: you may find it useful to know that both `shell-command` and `shell-command-on-region` take an optional output buffer argument, as either a buffer or a buffer name; if a buffer by the name given does not exist, a new buffer by that name will be created. See the internal documentation (`C-h f function-name RET` or `M-x describe-function RET function-name RET`) for more.